# Can PNP BJT have its collector grounded?

Tags: transistors, motor

I am designing a piezoelectric motor driver

To save me inverting the H-bridge driving signal to provide a differential signal (as would be needed in the H-bridge shown) can I flip one side of the bridge so that the PNP is at the 'bottom' and therefore has it's collector directly connected to ground? Therefore I could driver both sides of the bridge from the same signal

[image: H-bridge]

Comment: Your schematic does not match your text.  Could you show what you're actually intending to do?

Answer (score 2):

You could replace all BJT's by n-channel mosfets, then you don't need to *invert* the driving signals.
However, the Law of Conservation of Misery will apply: you now need to *level shift* the signals for the upper n-channel mosfets to drive them correctly: it will not simplify the circuit or reduce the number of components.

Answer (score 1):

It's not obvious what you intend, but, NO you can't.
The high side PNP switch needs to provide power from the +ve supply rail. The control signal needs to be negative relative to the positive rail.

There are selected cases where you  could use an input signal to drive the low and hjgh 
 side drivers -  but this would be unusual and not commonly possible.

Answer (score 1):

With either type of transistor, if you connect the collector to either supply rail, you've converted it from a common-emitter configuration (saturated switch) into a common-collector configuration (voltage follower).

When you switch configurations like this, the drive requirements change, and the efficiency of the circuit will be affected as well.

Answer (score 1):

"
Therefore I could driver both sides of the bridge from the same signal
"

Nor really.If you move Q3 down to the Q4 location, the drive requirement will be similar to but not identical to the req for Q1.  Also, unless the Q3 drive goes below ground, Q3 will be acting as an emitter-follower, not a saturated switch.  I don't think the net change in effort is less than driving Q1 and Q2 with the same-but different-signal.